# JPA - include entity without id column

Tags: java, jpa

I have a database with 2 tables: House and Cottage.
Each table has an ID column, containing the primairy key.
The Cottage table has a column "HouseID", which contains a foreign key to the House record.

Now, in my House entity class, I need to include the Cottage object.

How do I annotate the Cottage object in the House entity class to include the information. Do I need to add additional annotations in the Cottage entity class?

Is this suffisant ?

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Cottage cottage;
```

The House table does not contain a foreign key to Cottage table.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add @JoinColumn to the House entity

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="HouseID")
private Cottage cottage;
```

*name* should be the name of the referenced table column

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the foreign key with the `@JoinColumn` annotation:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "HOUSE_ID")
private Cottage cottage;
```

The `"HOUSE_ID"` is the actual name of the DB column, not a Java property.